# How can I ignore a property from being serialized in auto generated WSDL?

Tags: c#, web-services, xml-serialization

I have a web service and I need an additional property in my class when working on the server, but I don't want this property to be seen on the client (not serialized in the WSDL). I've tried `[XMLIgnore]`, but it didn't work. I additionally added `[Serializable]` on my class, in this case the property was serialized under different name `_x003C_MyPublicField_x003E_k__BackingField1`. Is there a way to do this without writing my own serializer ?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have also tried this [Omit Properties from WebControl Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039794/omit-properties-from-webcontrol-serialization) but with no luck.

Comment: have you tried `[NonSerialized]` ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Dose the property have to be public? Will setting it to private or protected solve the problem?

Comment: @Kritner I played a little with it and it finally worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `[NonSerialized]` attribute to prevent class properties from being serialized. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public int MySerializedProperty { get; set; }

    [NonSerialized]
    public string MyNonSerializedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `MyClass` should be decorated with `[Serializable]`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the [DataMember] attribute??

Comment: There are no data member attributes